# HTML - How do I add days to an input date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an alert to user when choose a date. For example, when user choose 2018-09-13, then the alert will show message "7 days later will be 2018-09-20". But instead, the alert message shows 2018-09-137.

```
<input type="date" name = "date" id = "date" onchange="javascript:var chooseDate=(this.value)+7; alert('7 days later will be '+chooseDate);" >
```

How should I add days into the date ?? please help, thank you.

Comment: see [date object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) - getDate/setDate is what you'll be interested in

Comment: JaromandaX is right. See setDate and then getDate. If you want to follow above method, this will make your answer `<input type="date" name = "date" id = "date" onchange="javascript:var chooseDate=this.value.substring(0,this.value.lastIndexOf('-')+1)+(parseInt(this.value.substring(this.value.lastIndexOf('-')+1,this.value.length))+7).toString(); alert('7 days later will be '+chooseDate);" >`. But it's not recommended.

Seriously, I hate adding inline js codes

Comment: `this.value` will be a string. You have to convert the date to integer before adding 7. I'm not making it as answer because the above method is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.value` will return the date as `string` using the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, so if you "add" `7`, it will be `YYYY-MM-DD7`. What you could do is create a new `Date` object, and then add the days you want, like this:

```
var chooseDate=new Date(this.value);
chooseDate.setDate(chooseDate.getDate()+7);
alert('7 days later will be '+chooseDate);
```

This will give you the complete date, though, which is something you probably don't want, so you would have to get the values you actually need, like this:

```
var chooseDate=new Date(this.value);
chooseDate.setDate(chooseDate.getUTCDate()+7);
var futureDate = chooseDate.getFullYear()+'-'+('0'+(chooseDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0'+(chooseDate.getDate())).slice(-2);
alert('7 days later will be '+chooseDate);
```

Here you have a working example:

```html
<input type="date" name = "date" id = "date" onchange="var chooseDate=new Date(this.value);chooseDate.setDate(chooseDate.getUTCDate()+7);var futureDate=chooseDate.getFullYear()+'-'+('0'+(chooseDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+('0'+(chooseDate.getDate())).slice(-2);alert('7 days later will be '+futureDate);" >
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this in :

```
addDays = function(input_date, days) {
    var date = new Date(input_date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
```

You then call do addDays(this.value, 7) in onchange().

And, please reference on [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Comment: Thanks. But the return result shows like `Thu Sep 20 2018 08:00:00 GMT+0800` , how do I let it return just only date like `2018-09-20`.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with string instead of a date object:

```js
function lPad(val) {
  return ((10 > val ? '0' : '') + val);
}

function add(input, unit, value) {
  var cur = input.value;
  var byValue = Number(value);
  if (!/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}$/.test(cur) || !/day|month|year/.test(unit) || isNaN(byValue)) {
    console.warn('invalid parameters!');
    return false;
  }
  var dt = new Date(cur.replace(/\-/g, '/'));
  if (!dt || isNaN(dt)) {
    console.warn('invalid date!');
    return false;
  }
  if ('day' === unit) {
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + byValue);
  } else if ('month' === unit) {
    dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + byValue);
  } else {
    dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() + byValue);
  }
  input.value = [dt.getFullYear(), lPad(1 + dt.getMonth()), lPad(dt.getDate())].join('-');
  console.log(cur, value, unit, '=', input.value);
  return true;

}
```

```html
<input type="date" onchange="add(this,'day','+7');" title="+7 days" />
<input type="date" onchange="add(this,'month','-1');" title="-1 month" />
<input type="date" onchange="add(this,'year','+2');" title="+2 year" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one ...

```
<input type="date" name = "date" id = "date" onchange="ggrr(this)" >


<script>
function ggrr(input){

        var dateString = input.value;
var myDate = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(Date.parse(myDate));
var y = d.getFullYear();
var da = d.getDate() + 7;
var m = d.getMonth();
console.log(y+':'+m+':'+da);
}
</script>
```